# Can't go into webview from a listview on item click

Tags: android, listview, webview, android-listview, android-webview

I have a problem with this code, I can't get into the url which is defined in my listview item click, I got null pointer exception. I have created a permission for internet.

This is my code

Java

```
    public class UGSimpliyBeta extends Activity {
    ListView list_utama;
    Intent intent;
    WebView web;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ugsimpliy_beta);
        list_utama = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_utama);
        web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        String list_content[] = new String[]{"UG Web Service", "Schedule Service", "Exam Service", "Studentsite News", "About"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list_content)
                {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                    {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        /*YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR*/
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        return view;
                    }
                };

        list_utama.setAdapter(adapter);

        list_utama.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
            {
                Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                String content = item.toString();
                if(content.equals("UG Web Service"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(content.equals("Schedule Service"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(content.equals("Exam Schedule"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(content.equals("Studentsite News"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
                    final Activity activity = UGSimpliyBeta.this;
                    final ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                    progressdialog.setCancelable(true);
                    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
                    {
                        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                        {
                            progressdialog.show();
                            progressdialog.setProgress(0);
                            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                            if(progress == 100 && progressdialog.isShowing())
                            {
                                progressdialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    web.loadUrl("https://www.studentsite.gunadarma.ac.id/news/news.php");

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    intent = new Intent(UGSimpliyBeta.this, About.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id = "@+id/view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:scrollbars = "none">
</WebView>
```

activity_ugsimply_beta.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:background = "@drawable/tile">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width = "200px"
    android:layout_height = "200px"
    android:layout_above = "@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
    android:layout_centerVertical = "true"      
    android:src = "@drawable/app"/>
<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".UGSimpliyBeta" />
<ListView 
    android:id = "@+id/list_utama"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
    android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is for the logcat

```
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760): java.lang.NullPointerException
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at com.rk.ug_simplify.UGSimpliyBeta$2.onItemClick(UGSimpliyBeta.java:69)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  12-06 20:59:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(3760):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What makes it error and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting  setContentView again? Please make sure that the new content view contain webView.

Comment: I put it in order to change the view into webview, and I'm sure it the right layout for my webview xml

Comment: Probably the first content view does not have a WebView and when You do `web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);` it return null.

Comment: You may initialize webview once again after setting content view.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto are you sure that `web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);` return not null?

Comment: @Lemberg I've removed that line, but I still can't get what I want

Comment: in which layout is R.id.webview ?

Comment: I've update the code abouve. I put the webview.xml

Comment: Try to remove `setContentView(R.layout.webview);` but leave `web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);`

Comment: It still does not work :(

Comment: Try this setContentView(R.layout.webview);  web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.view);

Comment: Show your R.layout.activity_ugsimpliy_beta xml

Comment: @DevuSoman unfortunately does not work.

Comment: @Lemberg I've updated with activity_ugsimply_beta.xml

Comment: Try this: after setContentView(R.layout.webview); put this code web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.view);   But it is bed practice to call more than one time setContentView() in one Activity.

Comment: @Lemberg would you like to make your latest comment as an answer so I can up vote it and make it the right solution for my problem?? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: after `setContentView(R.layout.webview)`; 
put this code `web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.view);`

But it is bed practice to call more than one time setContentView() in one Activity.
It will be probably better to put your webView in another Activity or in Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

web is in the " activity_ugsimpliy_beta layout ". You are changing the content view to a new LAYOUT by saying  setContentView(R.layout.webview)  which doesn't contain web therefore the error is coming. Remove  setContentView(R.layout.webview); from your code and make list view invisible instead and it will run fine.